What Chord Progression is This?
I have this chord progression from an app,  Chordify. I like the sound, but the app doesn’t give me the key signature so I am unsure what the progression is.
Cm7 - Fm7 - A#7 - D#
The song is ‘save the last dance for me’
Is there enough context to figure out what this progression is, without the key signature?
Also - is the Cm7 acting as a secondary dominant to the Fm7? Can you do this with minor chords?

The last three are Fm7 - Bb7 - Eb, so II - V - I in Eb major. With this context the first one would rather be Db minor, so the minor chord on the low altered VII. Alternatively we can read this as Fb major (so a Neapolitan) over the low altered VII.

@Lazy Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Apologies, the # on the C#m7 was a typo! Should be Cm7. So it’s a vi - ii - V - I in Eb. I think the app generated chord names, so using D# etc. may be a glitch in how it presents.

Maybe - or absolutely, stop using naff apps. Nearly cost me dvs!!

Has Chordify heard of flat keys? We all know many guitarists who haven't!

This is my opinion only, but if you try playing this chord sequence and listen to it, but you get absolutely no ideas or feelings about where a home chord could be, then you lack fundamental musical skills. And a big concern should be, how to obtain those skills. It takes a bit of time, trial and error, but it's primarily a skill, something you can or cannot do, and much less about logical rules you "know". Like riding a bicycle or skating, it comes with practice. Again, my opinion.

Thinking enharmonically, D♭m7 > Fm7 > B♭7 >E♭ makes a lot more sense.
Personally, having played this for 60 yrs, I can't figure out where that sequence would (could) come in Save the Last Dance For Me.
Ignoring the 1st chord, the others will be a straightforward ii>V>I in key E♭. But where that D♭m7 fits defies me. Even if we call it C♯m7.
EDIT: now that the C♯m7 has been altered to Cm7, it all makes a lot more sense. Wish that had been spotted and rectified much earlier...
Cm7 is the relative minor 7 chord in key E♭, so no reason on earth why it should be picked out as strange! So, now, the sequence is vi > ii > V > I, as common a sequence as you'll find from the '60s.Bog standard rising 4ths.
Need to know which version, and where in the song!! This sentence refers to the OP..!

Since the question was corrected, why  not just remove the first part of your answer instead of adding an edit?

@JohnBelzaguy - I could, but having puzzled for a long time over that wrongly named chord, I feel entitled to leave that part in! Really did try and failed to figure out where it came!

@Tim Fair enough!

@Tim, sorry for the typo that caused the confusion

And as the answer from @JohnBelzaguy refers to, it is the Michael Buble version.

I would like to preface that on face value this progression is 6-2-5-1 in Eb (with enharmonic corrections) like mentioned previously. Beyond that since you mentioned this comes from “Save the Last Dance For Me”, I would also like to point out that these chords do not occur in this song in its original form.
The entire song originally is based on 1,4 and 5 chords. Another important point is that there is a lot more to this song than these four chords. Below is a basic chord sheet of the verse or A section. The only place where these chords can possibly occur in say, a stylized version like Michael Buble’s is in bars 14-18. I inserted them above the originals and labeled them as “Alt chords”. Even here your progression begins at the end of a 4 bar phrase so labeling it as 6-2-5-1 is a little out of context. My reason for posting this answer is to show that in this particular song 6-2-5-1 is not a progression, it is just a small part of a much larger one.


I always feel that after Ab in the middle 8, there should be Ao to return to the Eb.

For a start, any app that spews out the chord sequence Cm7 - Fm7 - A#7 - D# should be viewed with deep suspicion and distrust.    It's Cm7 - Fm7 - B♭7 - E♭.    And if that doesn't immediately make sense as a 'cycle of 5ths' progression homing on E♭, with all respect you are missing some basic concepts of functional chord progressions.

In that form it does make sense as a cycle of fifths.

This is a circle of fifth progression. Maybe you can adjust your app Chordify. I think there should be a button where you can choose sharp priority or flat priority.  If you download a file or import a Midi file, it will show the correct enharmonic chords.
From Chordify Support,

You can toggle between displaying flats and sharps but this is currently only possible on the website, not the app.
After opening a song, click the Edit tab, then you can click Signature to toggle between flats/sharps.


I agree with those who are replacing the A#7 and D# with their enharmonic equivalents. The chords from the app don't make sense because a computer, by definition, has no "sense". It cannot determine context, so it has not way to distinguish a D# from an Eb.
